# Is it possible to pin a vertex group in its current position during a cloth simulation?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to do a cloth simulation where it is simulated up to a certain frame, and then I want to pin a vertex group at the current state, allowing the simulation to continue. Currently if I try to keyframe pinning the vertices, they instantly snap to their original location. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.